# Routing multiple routes to the default page

Tags: routing

I have multiple routes that I need pointed at index.php to handle routing in a React app. Here's a list of routes:

```
/login
/logout
/profile
/sign-up
/coming-soon
/forgot-password
/content/:content_id
```

All I can seem to find information for is redirection and rewriting, but not a whole lot about routing. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

I have tried adding the following to my functions.php file:

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
   add_rewrite_rule('^login/?', 'index.php', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

and went to Settings => Permalinks and clicked Save changes, but navigating to http://myurl.com/login does not take me to index.php.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, pay attention to the code and its comments:

```
function my_custom_rewrite_for_react() {
    // Add to your resource 'index.php' a param and its value. Here I chose as an example 'custom_template' and the value '1'.
    add_rewrite_rule( '^login/?', 'index.php?custom_template=1', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( '^/logout/?', 'index.php?custom_template=1', 'top' );

    // WordPress does not know your custom param, so tell it.
    add_rewrite_tag( '%custom_template%', '([^&]+)' );

    /**
     * Filters the path of the current template before including it.
     *
     * @link    https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/
     */
    add_filter( 'template_include',
        /**
         * @param   string  The path of the template to include.
         */
        function ( $template ) {
            global $wp_query;

            // In this example 'chosen_template' equals to '1'.
            if ( ! empty( $wp_query->query_vars['custom_template'] ) ) {
                // $path will be equal to something like /var/www/my-app/public/wp-content/my-theme/index.php
                $path = STYLESHEETPATH . '/index.php';

                if ( file_exists( $path ) ) {
                    $template = $path;
                }
            }

            return $template;
        }
    );
}

add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_rewrite_for_react' );

// Delete this function once everything is working fine!
// Using the function bellow is the same as visiting the Permalinks page in admin.
flush_rewrite_rules();
```

By the way, your code actually works, but it's redirecting you with status 301 to *http://yoursite.com/index.php* which redirects you to *http://yoursite.com*, because that's how wordpress works.

To actually notice the redirecting you could open your terminal (Unix) and type `curl -v http://myurl.com/login` or `curl -v http://myurl.com/index.php`.

Comment: With this I am still getting a 404. I copied and pasted as-is into functions.php.

Comment: Odd. I tested the code myself and it's working fine.